# show that $z = 0$ is a branch point of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

I have the following function: $$f(z) = \left( \frac{z}{z+x_0} \right)^q,$$ where $q \in \mathbb Q, \ q = \frac{p}{r}$ with $p \neq r$ and $r \neq 0$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, $x_0 > 0$.

I want to show that $z = 0$ is a branch point.

My attempt: Calculate the contour integral $\oint f(z)dz$ on a loop around $z = 0$. If we get the same value for the starting point and endpoint, the integral should vanish. But, as we want to show that $z = 0$ is a branch point, the integral shouldn't vanish.

Let our starting point be $a = 0$ and our endpoint $b = 2\pi$.  We rewrite $z$ as $z(\theta) = re^{i\theta}$, where $r$ is the radius, i.e. the absolute value of $z$ and $\theta$ is the argument of $z$, i.e. $arg(z)$. We then calculate $z'(\theta) = rie^{i\theta}$ and let $r << 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. Then we have:

$$ \int_{\gamma} f(z)dz = \int_{a}^{b} f(z(\theta)) z'(\theta)d\theta = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}+x_0}  \right)^{q} r i e^{i\theta}d\theta \approx \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \frac{re^{i\theta}}{x_0} \right)^{q} r i e^{i\theta}d\theta \\ = \frac{ir^{q+1}}{x_0^{q}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i\theta(q+1)} d\theta = \frac{ir^{q+1}}{x_0^{q}} \frac{1}{i(q+1)} \left( e^{2\pi(q+1)i} - e^{0(q+1)i} \right) = \frac{ir^{q+1}}{x_0^{q}} \frac{1}{i(q+1)} \left( e^{2\pi(q+1)i} - 1 \right)
.$$

In the $4$th step I approximate $\left({re^{i\theta}+x_0}\right)$ in the denominator as $x_0$ because $r << 1$. The reasoning why the integral is not $0$ is that  $e^{2\pi(q+1)i} - 1 \neq 0$ for any $q$ as defined above.

Is the approximation that I made a valid step to made or can this be shown more rigorous?

Comment: Is there any restriction on $x_0$? It's just a real number?

Comment: @CunyiNan I edited the restriction on $x_0$.

Comment: How much less than 1 does $|re^{i\theta}|$ need to be for your approximation to be valid?

Comment: I think that, for the purpose to show that going around $z = 0$ and showing that the starting point does not equal the endpoint, $r$ can be taken as small as one wants it to be. But are you maybe suggesting that I make a Taylor expansion around $z = 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good exercise for me to review the branch cuts and points. To solve this question, I would prefer to start from basic definitions because it's easy to understand.

The function $f(z)$ can be written as $\sqrt[r]{z^{p}(z+x_0)^{-p}}$. Now let the first $z=r_{1}e^{i\theta_{1}}$ and the second $z+x_{0}=z-(-x_{0})=r_{2}e^{i\theta_{2}}$, so it turns to $\sqrt[r]{r_{1}^{p}r_{2}^{-p}e^{ip\theta_{1}-ip\theta_{2}}}$, by then we turn it into a geometry problem.

Consider the first counterclockwise circle centered at $z=0$, only the origin point inside. Let a point on the circle starts from $\theta_{1}=0$ and goes around one whole circle, the argument change is $+2\pi$ while the argument of $z=-x_{0}$ remains same, look back the polar form of $f(z)$ we shall find it becomes
$$\sqrt[r]{r_{1}^{p}r_{2}^{-p}e^{ip(\theta_{1}+2\pi)-ip\theta_{2}}}=\sqrt[r]{r_{1}^{p}r_{2}^{-p}e^{ip\theta_{1}-ip\theta_{2}}}e^{i\frac{2p\pi}{r}}=\sqrt[r]{r_{1}^{p}r_{2}^{-p}e^{ip\theta_{1}-ip\theta_{2}}}e^{i(2q\pi)}$$

You shall find when $q=\frac{p}{r}=k$ (here $k$ is an integer, it must be considered an integer is also a rational number), by $e^{2k\pi i}=1(k\in\mathbb{Z})$ the function value stays same. When $q$ is not an integer, $z=0$ is indeed a branch point.

BTW You can also do similar analysis to $z=-x_{0}$.

Comment: Thank You very much! It's a much simpler approach than I had with the contour integral.
Can You maybe additionally explain how would Your proof go if $q$ was irrational? Because then you can't write it as $q = \frac{p}{r}$.

Comment: If it's not rational, still use polar form to do similar analysis, the $e^{i2k\pi a}$ term ($a$ is irrational) cannot be $1$ any longer. It's impossible for letting $2ka$ be an integer. So it is infinite-valued function, $z=0$ will be a branch point forever.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again!

Comment: If we take $z = 0$ and go around it, does the radius have an impact on the fact if $z = 0$ is a branch point or not? https://peterefrancis.com/complex-function-plot/plotter.html# on this site i plotted the function $f(z) = (z/(z+3))^sqrt(2) and it seems like the function changes the phase "rapidly" when going over the negative real axis but only between z = -x_0 and z = 0.

Comment: Or am I interpreting the graph wrong?
Because it seems that if i would choose a radius bigger than  x_0, there wouldnt be such a change in phase... and by change in phase, i mean going from blue to green in the example which i gave above

Comment: Take the function you mentioned $f(z)=\sqrt{\frac{z}{z+3}}$ as example. If you choose circle centered at $z=0$ whose radius bigger than $x_{0}$, it means two points are all inside it. Let it goes around for one time, the phase(argument) cancels, so the function value stays same, meaning the point $z=\infty$(i.e. so so far from two points) is not branch point.

Comment: But where do I see this in Your answer that this is the case? Because for this example, $\sqrt{\frac{z}{z+3}}$, in your answer we would have $q = \frac{p}{r} = \frac{1}{2}$, therefore we would have $\sqrt{r_1 r_2^{-1} e^{i \theta_1 - i \theta_2} } e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{2}}$. And $e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{2}}$ simplifies to $e^{i \pi } = -1$. So we still don't have $e^{2 \pi i q} = 1$.

Comment: When $q=\frac{1}{2}$, $z=0$ and $z=-x_{0}$ are both branch points. If a complex function $f(z)$ is of form $f(z)=\sqrt[r]{(z-a_{1})^{p_1}\cdots(z-a_{n})^{p_{n}}}$, for a point $a_{k}$, if $p_{k}$ is not multiplier of $r$, then $a_{k}$ is a branch point.

Comment: But I still don't quite understand it because above you said if the radius was bigger than $x_0$, going one circle around we would end at the exact same point as we started. How could then $z = 0$ be a branch point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149489/discussion-between-cunyi-nan-and-syphracos).

Comment: Gladly! And thanks again!